# Ruby code block in view will deny anything inside from appearing in DOM (only with table element)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Getting Started rails guide on making a blog application and I'm wiring my second model to the show view of my first model. I wanted to add the data inside a table but anything inside the ruby statement will not appear in the DOM, but if I remove the html elements it will print just fine. I'm not familiar enough with ruby syntax yet to know if I'm doing something wrong.

Models: Client, Payment

app/views/clients/show.html.erb (snippet of part that's not working)

```
<% @client.payments.each do |payment| %>
    <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Development:</b></td>
                <td><%= payment.development %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Server:</b></td>
                <td><%= payment.server %></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
```

This is the entire view

```
<div class="clients show container">
    <h2>Clients - <strong>Show</strong></h2>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
            <td><%= @client.name %><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Issued on:</strong></td>
            <td><%= @client.date %><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Finished?</strong></td>
            <td>
            <% if @client.finished == true %>
                <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% else %>
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <% end %>
            <br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Notes:</strong></td>
            <td><%= @client.note %><br></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <% @client.payments.each do |payment| %>
    <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Development:</b></td>
                <td><%= payment.development %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Server:</b></td>
                <td><%= payment.server %></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
    <br><br>
    <h4>Add a payment</h4>
    <%= form_for ([@client, @client.payments.build]) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :development, :class => "form-label" %><br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <%= f.text_field :development, :class => "form-control" %>
            </div><br>
            <%= f.label :server_payments, :class => "form-label" %><br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                <%= f.text_field :server, :class => "form-control" %>
            </div><br>
            <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_client_path(@client), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', clients_path, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `<table> </table>` elements outside of the `do` block? You can keep the `<tr>` (etc). Unless you're trying to make a new table for each item.

Comment: I have but the problem persists.

Comment: Update: I had a very annoying syntax error in my Payments controller, still very curious as to why that wouldn't flag an error and mess with printing in the view.

Comment: Please provide more information like what your are getting and what you are expecting. Also provide errors that you are getting on your controller otherwise no can help you.

Comment: The problem has been solved and it was implied that there were no errors, hence the showing the view with oddities.